# WPF: Change GridView cell colors when two specific cells in the GridView differ in values

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I have the following problem: I have a `GridView` embedded into a `ListView`. It has two columns (the first and second ones) which initially have the same values in their cells, but by using other UI elements the user may able to change the value in a cell in the second column. What I want to do is to change the color of cells in the same `row`, when their values differ due to a change from the *UI*. Here is the `ListView` and `GridView` I am talking about:

[image]

Here, the first cells in both "Observation" and "Hidden State" columns should change their colors, indicating a difference in the values. And I have the following `XAML` code for the List and `GridViews`:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="6" Margin="10" Name="ObservationsListView" SelectionChanged="ObservationsListView_SelectionChanged_1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Observation" Width="122" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding observationStr}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Hidden State" Width="122" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stateStr}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="122" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding valueStr}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

What is the easiest way to do that? Simply, something like

```
 GridView.Columns[0].Cell[currentCellIndex].Color = RED
 GridView.Columns[1].Cell[currentCellIndex].Color = RED
```

would do fine for me, but I am aware that things are more complex in `WPF` due to all the data binding stuff. A short way solution like the above one would be great for my causes here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing that you can do is to add another property to your class that has the `observationStr` and `stateStr` properties in it. The new property should be of type `bool` and return `true` when the values do *not* equal each other and `false` when they do. Then you can data bind to that property in a `Trigger` in the grid to update the colour for you:

```
public bool AreValuesChanged
{
    get { return observationStr != stateStr; }
}
```

Of course, you'd also need to call the `NotifyPropertyChanged("AreValuesChanged")` method when you update the other two values to make this work:

```
public string observationStr // repeat for stateStr
{
    get { return _observationStr; }
    set { _observationStr = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(observationStr); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged(AreValuesChanged); }
}
```

For the colour change, you could add a simple `DataTrigger` into a `Style` - make sure that this is declared within scope of the `ListView` control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AreValuesChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that as soon as possible.

Comment: A question: When I call NotifyPropertyChanged(AreValuesChanged) in the set method of observationStr, how it is going to affect the DataTrigger in the ListView? If I see correctly, I need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in order to call NotifyPropertyChanged, so what should I do something in my implemented version of NotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: There are several different ways to implement that... see the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.